# I can't get my httpOnly cookie from my post request using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, axios, jwt

I am having an issue where I am not able to grab my cookies from my node.js backend. Below is my current code and when I console.log(req.cookies) It returns [Object: null prototype] {}. I had a similar issue in the past and the way I fixed that was just by adding "withCredentials: true" but since I already have that on my axios post request I don't believe that to be the issue.

**Front-end**

```
  const save = async () => {
    if (loggedInCookie) {
        await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/savelisting', {
            withCredentials: true,
            link: link,
            car: car,
            price: price,
            picture: picture,
            timeleft: timeleft,
            site: site,
            milage: milage,
            location: location,
            trans: trans
        });

    } else {
        console.log("please login to save this listing")
    };

};
```

**Backend**

```
app.post('/savelisting', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.cookies);

    try {
    var jwtToken = await req.cookies.AccessToken;
    console.log(jwtToken);

    // Grooms cookie
    jwtToken = jwtToken
                    .split('; ')
                    .find(row => row.startsWith('AccessToken='))
                    .split('=')[1];


    const decoded = jwt.verify(jwtToken, process.env.TOKEN_KEY);
    var userId = decoded.id
    console.log(userId) 
 
    const link = req.body.link;
    const car = req.body.car;
    const price = req.body.price;
    const picture = req.body.picture;
    const timeleft = req.body.timeleft;
    const site = req.body.site;
    const milage = req.body.milage;
    const location = req.body.location;
    const trans = req.body.trans;

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    };
    res.status(200).send();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the `withCredentials` setting as part of the data to your API. It should be passed as an option to axios:

```
axios.post(
    'http://localhost:5000/savelisting',
    {    
        link: link,
        car: car,
        ...
    },
    {
        withCredentials: true
    }
)
```